# How do I make the dataframe within an R function globally accessible?

Tags: r, function, rvest

I've made this R script for pulling lyrics and the album name using `rvest` from a lyrics website.

```
songscrape <- function(y, a) {
  url <- y
  artist <- a
  
  SongsListScrapper <- function(x) { 
    page <- x
    songs <- page %>% 
      read_html() %>% 
      html_nodes('.listalbum-item') %>% 
      html_text() %>% 
      as.data.frame()
    
    
    chart <- cbind(songs)
    names(chart) <- c("Songs")
    chart <- as.tibble(chart)
    return(chart)
  }
  
  SongsList <- map_df(url, SongsListScrapper)
  SongsList
  
  SongsList %<>%
    mutate(
      Songs = as.character(Songs) 
      ,Songs = gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", Songs) 
      ,Songs = tolower(Songs) 
      ,Songs = gsub(" ", "", Songs) 
    )
  
  SongsList$Songs
  
  #Scrape Lyrics 
  
  wipe_html <- function(str_html) { 
    gsub("<.*?>", "", str_html)
  }
  
  lyrics2 <- c()
  albums2 <- c()
  number <- 1
  
  for(i in seq_along(SongsList$Songs)) { 
    for_url_name <- SongsList$Songs[i]
    
    #clean name
    for_url_name <- tolower(gsub("[[:punct:]]\\s", "", for_url_name))
    #create url
    paste_url <- paste0("https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/", artist,"/", for_url_name, ".html")
    
    #open connection to url 
    for_html_code <-read_html(paste_url)
    for_lyrics <- html_node(for_html_code, xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[5]")
    for_albums <- html_node(for_html_code, xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[11]/div[1]/b
")
    for_lyrics <- wipe_html(for_lyrics)
    for_albums <- wipe_html(for_albums)
    lyrics2[number] <- for_lyrics
    albums2[number] <- for_albums
    
    number <- number +1
    
    show(paste0(for_url_name, " scrape complete!"))
    
    Sys.sleep(10)
  }
  
  songs2 <- cbind(lyrics2, albums2) %>% as.data.frame()
  songs2$albums2 <-  gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", songs$albums2)
  

}
```

The function `songscrape` takes in two argument, `y` and `a` which are the primary artist page on A-Z lyrics and the artist name in the url (for example, `songscrape("https://www.azlyrics.com/i/ironwine.html", "ironwine")`)

When I run this, I can see the status messages pop up in the console like: `"thenightdescending scrape complete!"` so I know the function taking in the arguments correctly but I tried stopping it midway to check if everything was fine and I when I type in:

`View(lyrics2)` or `View(songs2)`, it gives me `Error: object 'songs2' not found`.

I haven't worked with R functions before, this is my first time but I'm guessing this is because the scope of these objects is limited to only within the function. How do I make these accessible outside the function and have the function output these objects as dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of two ways to achieve this. The first is to return a list. Since you can save dataframes in lists, this should work.

```
foo <- function(x, y){
  i = x+1
  k <- y+1
  return(list(i, k))
}

df <- foo(1, 1)
```

another way to code this could be:

```
foo <- function(x, y){
  i = x+1
  k <- y+1

  df <- list()

  df$first <- i
  df$second <- k
  return(df)
}

df <- foo(1, 1)
```

You can create single dataframes afterwards with extracting the values from the returned list:
`df[1]` etc.

---

The second method is to use the `<<-` operator, which outputs the values in the global environment. But I do not recommend using this method. In general you want your function be a closed environment, but it can be useful for debugging. Always return your wanted output with `return()`

```
foo <- function(x, y){
  i = x+1
  k <<- y+1
}

foo(1, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! When I use `return(df)`, is this printing the df or saving the `df` object to the global environment? If it is doing the latter then it's okay I guess. Additionally, should I be using `df <- foo(1,1)` to save the results from the function? This ties in with my first question because I'm not really sure where the output is being saved when the function is running.

Comment: @Aman I guess the easiest way is to try it out. But I can explain: when you use `return()` you will get your values into the global environment. The variable by itself is not returned, just the values. Therefore you use `df <- foo(1,1)`. If you are not saving it, you will print it to your console. So `foo(1,1)` is literally the values of the `return()`. You also just can return one variable, list, dataframe etc. That's why using nesting a list is a typical way to return multiple values.

Comment: Ahhh that clears a lot of things up! I always assumed that the object inside `return()` is saved to the global environment rather than just being printed. Thank you so much. I might follow up with this in a while (the scraper is running with the changes you suggested), I hope that is okay! Marking your answered accepted though :)